# Media Element Display H264 bitstream [UWP]

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, uwp, h.264, mediaelement

I am developing an application that should play streaming video

I am trying to play h264 streaming video in `MediaElement`, but MediaElement remains empty

I use `FFmpeg` as the video source

```
ffmpeg -r 20   -f gdigrab   -i desktop   -f mpegts  -vcodec libx264 udp://127.0.0.1:5555
```

On the client-side (*UWP*) I use the `FFmpegInterop` library
The codec and resolution of the video are detected correctly, but the `MediaElement` does not play anything

I've also tried using MJPEG, for example

```
ffmpeg -r 20 -f gdigrab -i desktop -f mjpeg -vcodec mjpeg udp://127.0.0.1:5555
```

Everything works correctly.
*RTSP* stream also works, for example from *OBS studio*, and in this case, the codec is defined as h264

It turns out that the problem can only be on the transmitting side? Is it possible to use only the UDP protocol for this purpose? Maybe I missed some FFmpeg settings?

```
 private async void MediaPlayer_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            MediaPlayer.Loaded -= MediaPlayer_Loaded;

            FFmpegInteropLogging.SetDefaultLogProvider();
            FFmpegInteropConfig options = new FFmpegInteropConfig();
            options.PassthroughVideoH264 = true;
            options.SkipErrors = 1000;
            options.PassthroughVideoHEVC = true;
            options.PassthroughVideoH264Hi10P = true;
           decoder = awaitFFmpegInteropMSS.CreateFromUriAsync("udp://127.0.0.1:5555",options);

            var mediaStreamSource = decoder.GetMediaStreamSource();
            mediaStreamSource.BufferTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
            Debug.WriteLine(decoder.VideoStream.CodecName);

            MediaPlayer.MediaFailed += MediaPlayer_MediaFailed;
            MediaPlayer.SetMediaStreamSource(mediaStreamSource);
            MediaPlayer.Play();
}
```

Comment: Are there any errors? Does the MediaFailed event been triggered?

Comment: Hello, MediaFailed event was didn`t triggered; I also added a SampleRequested Event to MediaStreamSource, where I output various properties of CurrentVideoStream for debugging purposes;  For example width and height, HardwareDecoderStatus.  It works, HardwareDecoderStatus = available. I noticed that sometimes the width and height are set to 0x0, but restarting the application fixes this

Comment: SampleRequested Event triggered only, when i try to play UDP/MJPEG stream or RTSP h264 stream. If  i use ffmpeg -r 20   -f gdigrab   -i desktop   -f mpegts  -vcodec libx264 udp://127.0.0.1:5555   SampleRequested Event didn`t triggered

Comment: UPD. It seems that setting the property VideoDecoderMode = VideoDecoderMode.ForceFFmpegSoftwareDecoder solved the problem.

Comment: Happy to hear that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the property VideoDecoderMode = VideoDecoderMode.ForceFFmpegSoftwareDecoder solved the problem.